# how to org mode image absolute path of export html?

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode

I need to export absoluted Image url in html in emacs org-mode file:

when i write the following code:

```
[[file:/images/a.jgp]]
```

export of html code is :

```
<img src="file:///images/a.jpg" >
```

but which i need is :

```
<img src="/images/a.jgp">
```

so how can i export what i wanted , instead of use `#+BEGIN_HTML` tag ?

ps: my emacs config:

```
 16 ;; org-mode project define
 17 (setq org-publish-project-alist
 18       '(
 19         ("org-blog-content"
 20          ;; Path to your org files.
 21          :base-directory "~/ChinaXing.org/org/"
 22          :base-extension "org"
 23 
 24          ;; Path to your jekyll project.
 25          :publishing-directory "~/ChinaXing.org/jekyll/"
 26          :recursive t
 27          :publishing-function org-publish-org-to-html
 28          :headline-levels 4
 29          :html-extension "html"
 30          :table-of-contents t
 31          :body-only t ;; Only export section between <body></body>
 32          )
 33 
 34         ("org-blog-static"
 35          :base-directory "~/ChinaXing.org/org/"
 36          :base-extension "css\\|js\\|png\\|jpg\\|gif\\|pdf\\|mp3\\|ogg\\|swf\\|php\\|svg"
 37          :publishing-directory "~/ChinaXing.org/jekyll/"
 38          :recursive t
 39          :publishing-function org-publish-attachment)
 40         ("blog" :components ("org-blog-content" "org-blog-static"))
 41         ))
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The way to do this is to register a new kind of link in org-mode, using `org-add-link-type`. That lets you supply a custom export format.

`org-add-link-type` requires a prefix, a "what happens when you click the link?" function, and an export function.

I use a prefix of `img`, so my links look like `[[img:logo.png][Logo]]`.
My image files are in `../images/` (relative to the .org files), and from the webserver they show up in `/images/`. So for those settings, putting this in `.emacs` provides the solution:

```
(defun org-custom-link-img-follow (path)
  (org-open-file-with-emacs
   (format "../images/%s" path)))

(defun org-custom-link-img-export (path desc format)
  (cond
   ((eq format 'html)
    (format "<img src=\"/images/%s\" alt=\"%s\"/>" path desc))))

(org-add-link-type "img" 'org-custom-link-img-follow 'org-custom-link-img-export)
```

You'll probably need to amend the paths for your setup, but that's the recipe. As you'd expect, <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd>`org-add-link-type` will give you the full gory details.

Oh, and for what it's worth, here's the code I'm using for inter-post links (like `[[post:otherfile.org][Other File]]`). There's a little Jekyll magic in the output format, so watch the double-%s.

```
(defun org-custom-link-post-follow (path)
  (org-open-file-with-emacs path))

(defun org-custom-link-post-export (path desc format)
  (cond
   ((eq format 'html)
    (format "<a href=\"{%% post_url %s %%}\">%s</a>" path desc))))

(org-add-link-type "post" 'org-custom-link-post-follow 'org-custom-link-post-export)
```

Comment: I want to use iimage-mode , this method will not support it ? how to ?

Comment: This is excellent, thanks. Do you know how I can get emacs to inline images using the `img:` link type with `org-redisplay-inline-images`?

Comment: A note: Org-mode v 9. reports the org-add-link-type as obsolete (although the export still works and generates the required img src="/etc/anImg.png"). An email to the [org mailing list](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2017-04/msg00188.html), suggested a solution for org-mode version 9: 

    (org-link-set-parameters
      "img"
      :follow 'org-custom-link-img-follow
      :export 'org-custom-link-img-export)

Comment: Hey! What would be the equivalent of this for markdown?

Comment: The documentation suggests doing this a different way as of now: [here](https://orgmode.org/manual/Adding-Hyperlink-Types.html)

Answer (score 2):

Another answer would be utilizing `#+ATTR_HTML`, see the following:

```
#+ATTR_HTML: :src /images/a.png
[[file:./images/a.png]]
```

With that, you'll be able to use inline images and export the way you want.

Comment: Elegant, simple, just what I needed. And it allows me to link to the image source in the org source, which allows me to actually see the image while editing, too. Great stuff. Thanks.